# Can だ be left off in informal sentences?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, nouns, copula

In declarative statements I’ve gathered that saying just 「これ新聞だ」for example would be too forward or a bit aggressive. So could you just say 「これ新聞」or even just 「新聞」for informal sentences?

I understand that い adjectives can be left on their own but I’m just not sure how to write informal sentences with な adjectives and nouns and not using です.

Comment: What's the context? Asking for the name of the object? Or are you trying to say "Here you go"?

Comment: i was just providing an example. what i mean is in declarative statements like “this is a newspaper” or “it’s a new show!”

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say using ~だ is "too aggressive", though it does have an aggressive feel to me. Especially if you are talking in an informal setting I wouldn't be too concerned with it. (It was formal, you would probably be using 〜です anyway)

I think you can often omit the だ for a softer feel, however in practice ~だね or ~だよ is pretty common, at least in informal conversation.

Answer (score 2):

adding だ without a particle ending as Locksleyu mentioned just seems kind of pointless in informal cases (to my ear). You would typically only add it in combination with a particle like ね or よ. And, instead in informal situations (as you mentioned) you would simply omit it.

Of course this is only in spoken Japanese that typically has a "looser" feel from a grammatical standpoint and is based more on the feeling. And, adding だ where not needed in spoken Japanese does indeed "feel" strange and would probably seem strange to the listener, as you mentioned.

Comment: I may disagree with one thing you said, that だ feels strange when not needed. To be specific, "これは新聞だ" sounds normal to me (though a little more aggressive), and "これは新聞" also sounds OK. However, "可愛いだよ" would be one case where it is grammatically incorrect and sounds awkward, not sure if you meant that sort of case (可愛いよ is natural and correct)